# Certificate chain for AWS ACM using Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, cloudflare, aws-acm, aws-access-policy

I'm trying to **Import a certificate** from Cloudflare using the [AWS Web UI](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) and I'm stuck in this page:

[image]

I read that the equivalent in Cloudflare to `Certificate Chain` is Origin Certificates (not 100% sure on this), so I created one and chose the `RSA certificate` and when I try to finish the import in AWS it says:

```
Could not validate the certificate with the certificate chain. Choose Previous button below and fix it.
```

Anyone knows what's the problem?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried the root CA and it also doesn't work:

[image]

This is the "solution" from AWS:

"Could not validate the certificate with the certificate chain."

If ACM can't match the certificate to the certificate chain provided, verify that the certificate chain is associated to your certificate. You might need to contact your certificate provider for further assistance.

Comment: cert chain is optional. You don't have to provide it if you don't have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the issue, I had created a Client CE and that’s what I was using, I read on the description that it was the one used to authenticate APIs in clients so it made sense. Anyway, resolution:

All 3 CE has to be ORIGIN and the root is from [this page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-CloudFlare-Origin-CA-#h_30cc332c-8f6e-42d8-9c59-6c1f06650639). So if anyone has this issue, make sure you use the CE from the Origin page + the root

[image]